# Issue in saving date , date_entered no saving in suitecrm all modules

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have issue in date_entered. It saves NULL instead of saving current date time stamp.

This issue is happening in all modules.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using. And if you are getting any errors post them too. Also post what you already have tried to solve this problem so we can rule out those solutions

Comment: suitecrm itself save date_entered field ,previously in  my records date_entered  saved automatically  ,from today i encourted this issue i have not done any code to save date_entered  field it (Suite crm) itself saves it

Comment: so why post it under PHP tag if you have no code? Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Default format of mysql date is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

If your column type is date or datetime, you have to store in `YYYY-MM-DD` format only.

If you wish to change date while storing to database,

```
$date = "date in any format";
date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```

And if you wish to change format of date while displaying, see formats [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the timedate global variable like this:

```
global $timedate;
$bean->date_entered = $timedate->nowDb();
```

***Here are some common troubleshooting steps:***

1. Make sure that you are correctly handling the bean for the record you wish to create:

   `$bean = BeanFactory::newBean("ModuleName");
   $bean->name = 'some value';
   $bean->property_name =  'some value';
   $bean->save();`
2. Ensure the file and folder permissions are correctly set for your instance. On an Ubuntu system you can run:

   `sudo cd /path/to/suitecrm | sudo chown www-data:www-data . -R && sudo chmod 775 . -R`
3. Run a *Quick Repair and Rebuild*

Comment: i have impletmented this it is not working saving date_entered as null in database

Comment: Are you calling the $bean->save() method?